# Can (1 - p-value) be the weight of a graph's edges?

Tags: statistical-inference

I understand that the p-value can be translated as the strength of the statistical tests' results.

From this perspective, can (1 - p-value) be the weight of an undirected graph's edges (like an adjacency matrix or weight matrix)?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItG98.png)

ex. We have a Pearson correlation of 0.8 and a p-value of 0.02 between A and B.
Of course, we can use the correlation as the weight of edges in the graph (normal graph). However, I would like to ask that the (1 - p-value) from the Pearson correlation test can also be the weight of the edges.

Comment: What graph are you referring to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.